using a Rust library from existing C++ application in Visual Studio
I need some advice regarding the static linkage of a Rust library into C++ application.
I am able to correctly link a very easy code without Rust dependencies and I am also able to link the code (even with dependencies) dynamically (*.dll), but I would like to embed the code into the C++ *.exe -> static link which makes many "unresolved external symbol" errors during VS build.
To demonstrate the issue I made a very easy code below. It works perfectly until I uncomment the reqwest library functionality, then only dynamic linkage (cdylib) starting to work...
What "trick" I am missing?
test/src/lib.rs:
// use reqwest::blocking::Client;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn connect() -> i32 {
    // let c = Client::new();
    // c.get("http://www.google.com").send().expect("failed");
    0
}

test/cargo.toml:
[package]
name = "test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
# crate-type = ["cdylib"]
crate-type = ["staticlib"]

[dependencies]
reqwest = { version = "0.12.9", features = ["blocking"]}

test/test.h:
extern "C" {

int32_t connect();

}  // extern "C"

test_c/src/main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

int main()
{
    int i = connect();
    std::cout << "connect -> " << i << "\n";
}

The errors I am getting from Visual Studio (version 2019) look like these:
Error       LNK1120    77 unresolved externals                                    test_c    test_c.exe  1   
Error       LNK2001    unresolved external symbol __imp_accept                    test_c    test.lib(std-2df1f22abef96888.std.1de697f09da2cdd5-cgu.0.rcgu.o)    1   
Error       LNK2001    unresolved external symbol __imp_accept                    test_c    test.lib(socket2-220b4c5575b738d5.socket2.195adf5aa58b4623-cgu.1.rcgu.o)    1   
Error       LNK2001    unresolved external symbol __imp_accept                    test_c    test.lib(socket2-220b4c5575b738d5.socket2.195adf5aa58b4623-cgu.2.rcgu.o)    1   
Error       LNK2001    unresolved external symbol __imp_accept                    test_c    test.lib(socket2-220b4c5575b738d5.socket2.195adf5aa58b4623-cgu.0.rcgu.o)    1   
Error       LNK2001    unresolved external symbol __imp_AcceptSecurityContext     test_c    test.lib(reqwest-6591741496af5748.reqwest.d1308cb910735ad3-cgu.04.rcgu.o)   1   


Thank you very much in advance for any hint!

You are not linking against the standard Windows API libraries Ws2_32 and Secur32. (And probably more, those are just from the symbols you don't have resolved.)
If you link dynamically the Rust DLL is itself linked against the Win32 standard API libraries it requires.
I don't know how exactly you are linking statically (you haven't provided too much information about your build system), but my guess is that you are simply linking the Rust code together to a static library and then importing that static library into your C++ build, correct? In that case the static library of all of your Rust code (which hopefully also includes the Rust dependencies of your code and the Rust standard library) will have DLL dependencies itself, and you must explicitly link against those required DLL dependencies of the code your are including in your executable.
I don't know if this can be automated in some way, but explicitly adding the required Windows API DLLs to the list of external DLLs your C++ project links to should make this work.


but my guess is that you are simply linking the Rust code together to a static library and then importing that static library into your C++ build, correct?
Yes, that is exactly what I did...

Anyway, I tried to add Secur32.lib to [Additional Dependencies] as you mentioned and now the number of errors decreased. Thank you!
So the new questions is, is there a tool able to make a list of missing dependencies? I saw in another discussion that there is command line option for Rust compiler (rustc): --print=native-static-libs... Is that what I am looking for? I am going to try it...

Yes, you can run cargo build --verbose (after running cargo clean first), and it will show you the rustc command it uses for compiling.  Remove the --error-format=json from that command line, add the --print=native-static-libs, and you'll get a list of native libraries that it links to. (Possibly with a -l prefix due to how Rust uses the LLVM linker.) Unfortunately I don't know of any way of doing this with just Cargo.

Thanks so much again! Finally, I can build the exe with a statically linked Rust library. Just for info, the following modules have to be defined to VS linker:
test.lib
secur32.lib
WS2_32.lib
crypt32.lib
bcrypt.lib
Userenv.lib
RuntimeObject.lib
Ncrypt.lib
advapi32.lib
kernel32.lib
ntdll.lib
